# Is there a itemsep equivalent for subitem?

Tags: spacing, lists, description

So I was wondering if there is the equivalent of `itemsep` for the subitems, particularly in the `description` environment. I know I could nest many environments one in the other but it seems ugly.

Exemple:

```
\begin{description}\itemsep2ex   
    \item[first item] \hfill\\
        \subitem \hfill\vspace{-1ex}\\
            some text
        \subitem \hfill\vspace{-1ex}\\
            some more text
        \subitem \hfill\vspace{-1ex}\\
            more text   
    \item[second item]
        \subitem some text 
\end{description}
```

This gives me what I want, but is there a way of replacing the 3 `\vspace{-1ex}` following the subitems by a general command for all the environment?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for. As you note, it's possible to have nested `description` environments, both in "standard" LaTeX as well as in conjunction with packages such as `enumitem`. Please consider revising your posting to include a MWE (minimum working example) of what you've done so far (and, possibly, what you're hoping to avoid).

Comment: @Mico Sorry, just updated

Comment: Ugliness is in the eye of the beholder. Having nested lists is semantically well behaved whereas having a `\subitem` command abuses the semantics. Most editors support environment completion or macros that can speed up the inputting of the semantically well-formed source.

Comment: @AlanMunn I said `it seems ugly` :). I don't know  enough about LaTeX formatting standarts. If the community agrees I would gladly accept this as an answer. (By the way I am using TeXShop/vim and sometimes Kyle, any known manual on how to automate this kind of behavior?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the help of the [enumitem](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem) package, it's straightforward to set different fonts and font shapes for the labels of items of varying hierarchical levels in a `description` list. The following MWE keeps the default for labels of level-1 description items (bold) but uses non-bold *italics* for the labels of level-2 description items. (If you wanted to use plain non-italics for the labels of level-2 description items, just leave off the `\itshape` directive.) Hopefully you can find some combination of font shapes and weights which doesn't strike you as ugly...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[description,2]{font=\normalfont\itshape} % non-bold italics
\begin{document}
\section{Hello}
\begin{description}
  \item[First item] Initial thoughts \ldots
  \begin{description}
    \item[Preliminaries] The quick brown fox jumps \ldots
    \item[Further stuff] \ldots\ over the lazy dog.
  \end{description}
  \item[Second item] Further thoughts \ldots
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: More great packages... thanks! That is pretty neat too.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you could define a custom `\MySubitem`:

```
\def\MySubitem{\subitem \hfill\vspace{-1ex}\\ }
```

and then use `\MySubitem` when you want the `\hfill\vspace{-1ex}\\` applied and the regular `\subitem` when you *don't* want it applied (as in your last usage).  So with the MWE below you get output as your example:

[image]

### Notes:

- If you always wanted the same behavior, you could just redefine `\subitem`:

  ```
  \let\OldSubItem\subitem
  \def\subitem{\OldSubItem \hfill\vspace{-1ex}\\ }
  ```

  I did this originally but then saw that you were not applying your tweak to you last usage of `\subitem`.

### Warning:

- This is an abuse of `\subitem`. As egreg commented below `\subitem` is an internal command for typesetting the index and is not intended to be used in this manner.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\MySubitem{\subitem \hfill\vspace{-1ex}\\ }

% If you want to redefine \subitem uncomment the following:
% \let\OldSubItem\subitem%    
% \def\subitem{\OldSubItem \hfill\vspace{-1ex}\\ }

\begin{document}
\begin{description}\itemsep2ex 
    \item[first item] \hfill\\
        \subitem \hfill\vspace{-1ex}\\
            some text
        \subitem \hfill\vspace{-1ex}\\
            some more text
        \subitem \hfill\vspace{-1ex}\\
            more text   
    \item[second item]
        \subitem some text 
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is quite nice. May I ask why you use the `\let` before the `\def`?

Comment: That was left over form my first version where I was redefining `\item`. I have added a commented version to show how that could be used.

Comment: You're abusing `\subitem` which is an internal command for typesetting the index (it expands to `\@idxitem\hspace*{20pt}`). And `\@idxitem` uses `\hangindent` which doesn't go along with list environments that use `\parshape`: mixing the two is a sure source of headache. In the LaTeX manual, `\subitem` is mentioned *only* in connection with indexes.