# gap between first and second tier of a list

Tags: formatting, itemize

i use the itemize environment in my document to make listings. since i don't want the listings to take so much space, i always use \itemsep-10pt. However the gap between the first and second level of the listing doesn't get smaller by using the itemsep-command. how can i get rid of that gap?
MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\itemsep-10pt
\item first item first lvl
\item second item first lvl
\begin{itemize}
\itemsep-10pt
(HUGE GAP HERE)
\item first item second lvl
\item second item second lvl
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a itemsep equivalent for subitem?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58164/is-there-a-itemsep-equivalent-for-subitem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use enumitem for that without inserting manual actions

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{enumitem,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
\item first item first lvl
\item second item first lvl
\begin{itemize}[nosep]
\item first item second lvl
\item second item second lvl
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

See the manual for the difference between `noitemsep` and `nosep` options

Comment: this solved the problem, thank you :) is there a way of setting "nosep" as standard setting for all "itemize" environments i use?

Comment: @Max In the preamble: `\setlist[itemize,1]{noitemsep}
\setlist[itemize,2]{nosep}` to maintain percusse's settings or `\setlist[itemize]{nosep}` to have `nosep`.

Comment: thanks to you, too! i don't really see the difference between nosep and noitemsep for the first itemize-lvl. i mean the manual says, nosep "removes all vertical spacing", but is there any other verticalspacing than just the itemsep in the first lvl?

Comment: @Max Distance to the surrounding paragraphs etc.

Comment: ok, got all my answers now, thank you very much once again, guys.